# SVG element with clippath prevents events on underlying element

Tags: svg, clip-path

**Edit:** Maybe I need to test my assumption...
Is there a way to render svg so an element underlying another element can receive events?

[image: ![enter image description here]

The red circle does not respond to its hover event **where it is under** the clipped circle.

The rectangle iindicates the masked and clipped area of the green circle.
I want the visible red and green areas to both receive pointer events.
How would I get the whole red circle to respond - It has to underly the green circle.

[Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/mahks/gtyxc8nr/74/)

```
<svg id="svg_wrp" width="600" height="600" style='z-index:2'>
  <defs>
    <mask id="green_mask">
      <circle cx="300" cy="300" r="200" fill="#fff"></circle>
      <rect x="100" y="50" width="400" height="200" fill="#000"></rect>
    </mask>
    <clipPath id="green_clip">
      <rect x="100" y="50" width="400" height="200" fill='#000'></rect>
    </clipPath>
  </defs>
  <!-- Following for reference only -->
        <rect x="100" y="50" width="400" height="200" stroke="#080" fill="none"></rect> 
        <circle cx="300" cy="300" r="200" fill="rgba(0 0 255 /.2)" stroke="#080"></circle>
   <!-- Above for reference only -->
  <g>
    <circle cx="300" cy="50" r="100" fill="rgba(255 0 0 /1)" class="hover_it" ></circle>
    <!-- Following circle will have top part hidden, but mask does not prevent events  -->
    <circle id="green_hide_area"        
    cx="300" cy="300" r="200" fill="rgba(0 255 0 /1)" class="hover_it" mask="url(#green_mask)" ></circle>
  </g>
  <g>   
    <!-- Following circle will prevent events -->
    <circle id="green_event_stop"       
    cx="300" cy="300" r="200" fill="transparent" clip-path="url(#green_clip)" ></circle>
  </g>
</svg>


.hover_it{opacity:.5}
.hover_it:hover{opacity:1}
```

Comment: you are covering it with the transparent circle with a clip-path: the last group in the svg. change the fill from transparent to something else to see it.

Comment: @enxaneta Yes I know, how can I clip the green circle, so the red can receive an event?

Comment: I would need to understand what you want to achieve. Why do you need the last circle? You can add `pointer-events:none`. But is it what you want?   Alternatively you can use `fill="none"` instead of `fill=""transparent`

Comment: The last circle clips an area, so the underlying circle can receive an event.I can't use a mask because it does not suppress events in the masked area, so I have to do both, a mask to hide and a clip to stop events. Problem is the clip stops events for other elements as well.

Comment: @enxaneta I could not find a way to have fill="none" or  pointer-events:none solve the issue. Could you modify the fiddle as to how it does? Thanks!